# Predictions using perturbative renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

If physical quantities such as renormalized masses and couplings are fixed by experiment, what exactly are physicists using calculative perturbative renormalization techniques for?

Comment: I.e., what kinds of things are they predicting if not those quantities?

Comment: If a theory is renormalizable, the number of parameters that have to be fixed by experiment is finite. But the number of cross sections and decay rates that can be computed perturbatively and compared to those experiments is infinite.